# Javascript: Iterate through objects

Tags: javascript, object, loops

### I'm iterating through this object:

```
var object = { 
   first : {
      child1 : 'test1',
      child2 : 'test2'
   },

    second : {
       child1 : 'test3',
       child2 : 'test4'
    },

   first : {
      child1 : 'test5',
      child2 : 'test6!'
   }
};
```

### with this:

```
for(var attribute in object){
    alert(attribute + " : " + object[attribute]);
}
```

First it seemed that it works, but it iterates only on child objects with unique name, so the first object with: `first` is skipped.

### So what's the proper solution to iterate through an entire object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript objects are associative maps, and cannot have multiple values with the same key (name). Your data cannot have that structure.

Another option might be an array of key-value pairs.

```
var object = [
   ["first", {
      child1 : 'test1',
      child2 : 'test2'
   }],
   ["second", {
       child1 : 'test3',
       child2 : 'test4'
   }],
   ["first", {
      child1 : 'test5',
      child2 : 'test6!'
   }]
];

var i, attribute, value;
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    attribute = object[i][0];
    value = object[i][1];
    alert("" + attribute + " = " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with the iteration, there's rather a problem with the object. The second property named `first` replaces the first `first`, erasing it.

Who's on first?